# AlertDialog with urls and text

Tags: android

I am trying to show in an android AlertDialog some text and some words to be clickable opening a web page. I am doing something wrong with it cause it does not open the link i am telling him and the hole text is clickable, which i am trying to avoid....
This is my code:

```
final SpannableString s = new SpannableString(
                        Html.fromHtml("<br><a href=\"http://google.com\">a new link</a>")
                        );

        final TextView tx1 = new TextView(this);
        tx1.setText(getString(R.string.librarytextpart1) 
                + s
                + getString(R.string.librarytextpart2));
        tx1.setAutoLinkMask(RESULT_OK);
        tx1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

        Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.ALL);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.library))
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                            }
                        })

                .setView(tx1).show();
```

When clicked on the SpannableString text in dialog, it shows the entire text is clickable ... and still does not open a webpage. For sure I don't understand something right from the documentation, but don't see what. Can you help, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Html.fromHtml() you receive the already formatted HTML text from a given String.

Applied to your case this would result in a "a new link" - but the "href" below is ignored by the Alert Dialog as it is not displaying HTML. So the linkifier does nothing on your code. Try commenting it out - the behaviour will keep the same.

With the Linkifier, you are able to turn arbitrary patterns of text (RegExes) into clickable Links. You may append for example a String matching your Regular Expression to a predefined "base" content URI. So it does not only work for Websites but for every Content URI used on Android. For more Info on that refer to the [Google DevSite](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/wikinotes-linkify.html).

You could use the Linkifier without Regular Expressions, there are a some standard patterns included. These are matching eMail-adresses, phone numbers, map coordinates or a website. So in order to make your solution work:

1. Set the spannable String to a normal URL (no HTML stuff)
2. Just add Links for the Type "WEB_URLS" (Linkify.WEB_URLS) (Linkify.ALL will "search" for all predefined patterns as stated above)

And it will work.

I adjusted your code, now in the AlertWindow, the URL "www.google.com" should be clickable:

```
final SpannableString s = new SpannableString("www.google.com");

    final TextView tx1 = new TextView(this);
    tx1.setText(getString(R.string.librarytextpart1) 
            + s
            + getString(R.string.librarytextpart2));
    tx1.setAutoLinkMask(RESULT_OK);
    tx1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

    Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.library))
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int id) {
                        }
                    })

            .setView(tx1).show();
```